# how can I create a list of lists if I have a list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an object that looks like this

```
public class CompletionRow
{
    public int Pass;
    public int Fail;
    public int Blocked;
    public int NA;
    public string DesignName;
    public double WorkWeek;
    public int CompletionStatus;
}
```

I want to create a list that contains another list with two of these values. For example, I want a list like this:

**Edit**

```
public class Vals
{
    string DesignName;
    int CompletionStatus;

}
List<List<Vals>> eachCustomer = new List<List<Vals>>();
```

If I have a my list of object like this:

```
List<CompletionRow> results = new List<CompletionRow>();
```

is it possible to get this into my double list? I've tried to do something with linq where I select a value and then use .ToList() but I couldn't figure out how to do this with an extra list inside.

Comment: `List<List<int>>` , inner list is `List<int>`, how can it contains `DesignName` and `CompletionStatus` ?

Comment: you're right my mistake. I'll edit now

Comment: You don't indicate how/why you want to go from a 1 dim list to 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd just use either a `Tuple<string, int>,` anonymous type, `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, or a concrete type that you define. It just depends on the context. Although if youre passing it out to another type, I'd create another class.

Then you can, as you suggested, use LINQ.

```
return results.Select(c => new { DesignName = c.DesignName, CompletionStatus = c.CompletionStatus }).ToList();
```

This is the anonymous type solution, but I'd be wary of that approach unless you're using it only in the scope of the defining function. Otherwise, use `Tuple` or a concrete type. Preferably the latter, of course.

You can't have a list that contains multiple items. That's just not what lists are. Unless you're looking for a dictionary:

```
return results.ToDictionary(c => c.DesignName, c => c.CompletionStatus);
```

That will create a dictionary (which if you append `.ToList()` will become a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`), where `DesignName` is the key and `CompletionStatus` is the value.

**Edit:**

Although looking at your particular phrase "which contains an inner list that has two properties from my object (the DesignName and the CoompletionStatus)," I'm a little confused. If you actually do want a `List<List<T>>` as your title suggests, the greatest common denominator between the type of `DesignName` and `CompletionStatus` is `object`. So this will be terrible to work with.

```
return results.Select(c => new List<object>() { c.DesignName, c.CompletionStatus }).ToList();
```

If you did, for whatever reason, actually decide you wanted that, I would *at least* leave it as a `List<object[]>`. But I can't imagine a single scenario where this would actually be useful.

**Edit 2:**

With the introduction of your `Vals` type to the original question, I don't really see how you'd make a `List<List<Vals>>` **but** a `List<Vals>` is easy and appropriate:

```
return results.Select(c => new Vals() { DesignName = c.DesignName, CompletionStatus = c.CompletionStatus }).ToList();
```

Comment: I agree with you. It would be a really big headache to have a bunch of lists. However, I think you Edit 2 may just work for me. I'm using a jquery library called jqPlot and to plot a multi-line graph, it requires lists inside lists (very nasty). thanks

Comment: @roshambo ah, yes, the always-frustrating case of graphs. They frequently forego any sense of strong-typedness. I've noticed that in a lot of providers. Fair enough. Well yes, any of these should work, depending on what you can force it to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to create a new list if you want:

```
 var newlist = results
               .Select(x => new { Name : x.DesignName,
                                  Status : x.CompletionStatus }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

"DesignName" property of CompletionRow class can be replaced with a list of Vals object:

```
public class CompletionRow
{
    public int Pass;
    public int Fail;
    public int Blocked;
    public int NA;        
    public List<Vals> DesignList { get; set; }
    public double WorkWeek;
}
```

This way, List< CompletionRow > results can hold list of Vals in it.